# Magento2 - Cronjob indexer not working properly

Tags: magento2, cron

I configured the cronjob that is responsible for reindexing my webshop correctly. Unfortunately the indexer is not updated. If I enable cron output I get 'Ran jobs by schedule.'. But when I go to the Index Management page I see that nothing is updated there.

When I manually run: php bin/magento indexer:reindex this values are updated.

Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you set the Magento 2 cron job setting or cpanel cron setting, if cpanel please post the command you gave for cron job, here or update it in your question.

Comment: Yes, I did configure the cronjob via cPanels. This is the command:  /usr/local/bin/php -c /usr/local/lib /home/iys/public_html/bin/magento cron:run > /dev/null where /usr/local/lib is the folder where php.ini is located.

Comment: By default, indexers are set to update on save. Try changing it to update on schedule: `php bin/magento indexer:set-mode schedule`. Does that work?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the solution to my problem. I already configured Magento to update by schedule instead of update by save.

Comment: [You can check my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355005/how-to-set-cron-job-for-reindex/36382529#36382529). Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento 2.0.x we added `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` for a long time in our cronjobs. **But this is not the real solution**. This is a really heavy command to run and can slow down production environment. Magento 2 has a complex partial reindexing mechanism, which you can read all about here: https://maxchadwick.xyz/blog/digging-into-magento-2-partial-reindexing-implementation.

Since Magento 2.1.x the issue is fixed for us and we do not need to add indexer:reindex anymore to our cronjobs.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I believe it is a bug in Magento 2.0. I have posted the issue on the Magento github at https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2855.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run cron twice. First to discover the jobs to run and second to execute them.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, so what I did was to create a new cron job just to re-index, by executing the re-index command:

> /usr/local/bin/php -c /usr/local/lib/php.ini 'your magento
>   home'/bin/magento indexer:reindex >/dev/null 2>&1

Please note that your PHP folder and `php.ini` folder could be different from mine.

I decided to use `>/dev/null 2>&1` because the log output of the re-index command has several lines so I do not wanted a large log file be created on time as I can see on the admin page if the re-index is done or not.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to **restart your cron service** in Host Server

To do so in Apache CentOS Use below command:

```
service crond stop
```